# Assertion error/exception on basic while loop

Tags: loops, exception, conditional-statements, assertion

Hello everyone I'm currently trying to learn java using University of Helsinki's MOOC Java course. I'm currently working on this problem:

Write a program that reads values from the user until they input a 0. After this, the program prints the total number of inputted values that are negative. The zero that's used to exit the loop should not be included in the total number count.

I'm running into this error: java.lang.AssertionError: Something strange happened. It may be that 'class NumberOfNegativeNumbers'class's public static void main(String[] args) method is missing
or your program crashed due to an exception. More information java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

I'd like to solve this without using assertions or catch's because it hasn't been covered, and just understand why this is happening. I've tried replacing the nextInt() with nextLine() and converting the string into an int using Integer.valueOf, as well as adding parameters for the else statement so that if num == 0 it would break, though it shouldn't be needed, as well as moving around my conditional statements.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberOfNegativeNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int count = 0;

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Give a number: ");

            int num = scanner.nextInt();

            if (num <= 0){
                count = count + 1;
                continue;
            } else if (num >= 0) {
                continue;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Number of negative numbers: " + count);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, according to an example I found on the internet for `Scanner.nextInt()`, it's expected to be used with `Scanner.hasNextInt()`, eg this example I copied from [a tutorial site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm):

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.*;

public class ScannerDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String s = "Hello World! 3 + 3.0 = 6.0 true ";

      // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

      // find the next int token and print it
      // loop for the whole scanner
      while (scanner.hasNext()) {

         // if the next is a int, print found and the int
         if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Found :" + scanner.nextInt());
         }
         // if no int is found, print "Not Found:" and the token
         System.out.println("Not Found :" + scanner.next());
      }

      // close the scanner
      scanner.close();
   }
}
```

So, likely you need to wrap your code in that hasNextInt() check.

Also, you might need to double check the control flow that will occur if the user enters a zero. A prompt: if scanner.nextInt() returns a 0, what happens in the code you posted? Another hint might be that only two characters need to change to fix the issue I'm pointing out obliquely here.